# How do I open this secret door in the first level?

Tags: dos, rise-of-the-triad

This is an older DOS game I use to play as a kid.  I've purchased the Apogee Throwback pack on Steam which included this game.

In the very beginning of the first level, there is a secret wall behind you where you start.  You can see that in the screenshot below (the wall has already been pushed open):

[image: Secret Wall]

If you proceed down the hallway beyond this secret wall, there is a locked door.

[image: Locked Door]

As you can see, if you attempt to open it, it says "This Door Appears to be locked."  How do I open it?  I've never done this as a kid and I've always wondered what was behind that door.

Comment: This brings back memories...

Comment: According to the wiki it is on a time delay: http://triadpedia.wikia.com/wiki/In_The_Thick_of_It_(E1A1) : Turn right from your starting point, destroy the torch, and activate the pushwall behind it. Inside is a small room and a hallway that leads to a locked door - it's on a time delay. It'll open in about 2 minutes, revealing a 1UP. Make sure to keep right after activating the touchplate.

Comment: @Lyrion looks like you're right.  A bit disappointing that after all these years I finally get to see what was behind that door only to find its a one up.  If you put that into an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The door is on a time delay, after 2 minutes the door should open up. And a 1UP is found.

Source: http://triadpedia.wikia.com/wiki/In_The_Thick_of_It_(E1A1)